# Reverse of L'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

under what condition the existance of lim(f/g) implies existance of lim(f'/g')?
I mean when can I sure that the reverse of L'Hospital's rule is correct?
Does twice differentiability of f and g works here? Or some weaker or stronger condition is needed?

Comment: Note that even if $\lim\frac fg$ and $\lim\frac{f'}{g'}$ exist they need not be equal

Comment: Please explain more, I think that if both exist then are equal for l'hospital's rule

Comment: However I mean under the conditions of the theorem of l'hos. Rule